# How can we handle recaptcha in Jmeter?

Tags: apache, testing, jmeter

I am trying to submit the form which has text values and recaptcha for security reasons. How can we handle recaptcha to submit the form using Jmeter?

Any help!

Answer (score 2):

1. [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) is an acronym which stands for

   > **C**ompletely **A**utomated **P**ublic **T**uring test to tell **C**omputers and **H**umans **A**part

   So most probably you will not be able to do this quickly and easily
2. [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html) is a Google service which is yet another implementation of the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test). Your JMeter test must focus **solely** on your application features, 3rd-party services, images, scripts, etc. must be out of the scope, in other words you **must** [exclude external resources from your JMeter test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

So I would recommend asking your application developers or devops to turn off the CAPTCHA challenge for the duration of the load tests (or for the test environment in total) as it does not add any value, just makes automated and load testing almost impossible.

---

Just in case you're a Google engineer load testing reCAPTCHA - you can use machine vision libraries like [OpenCV](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in conjunction with [neural network implementation](https://deeplearning4j.org/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) in order to recognize the images do what is needed to bypass the challenge. Just be aware that one of protection mechanisms checks will not allow to pass the CAPTCHA if you react too fast which is not compatible with load testing at all.